# Angular 2 Upgrade Adapter with Angular 1 Modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, upgrade

I'm following the documentation on the Angular 2 website to use the upgradeAdapter to run a hybrid Angular 2/Angular 1 application and am running into some trouble instantiating the app. This is what I see in the console in the browser:

```
Failed to instantiate module NG2_UPGRADE_0_ due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.config due to:
```

The config and constants, do exist. This leads me to believe that the UpgradeAdapter isn't upgrading the dependencies written in Angular 1 properly (or do I need to do this manually for all of my Angular 1 components?)

Is there something missing?

Here's what's present in my app.ts:

```
import { UpgradeAdapter } from '@angular/upgrade';

const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();

(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [
    //app dependencies
    'myApp.config',
    'myApp.constants',
    //3rd party dependencies
    'ngAnimate'
  ])
  .config(config)
  .run(run);

  /*@ngInject*/
  function config($httpProvider, $logProvider) {
  }

  /*@ngInject*/
  function run() {
  }

  upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
})();
```

and vendor.ts:

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import 'angular';
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
```

I'm also using Webpack as a module loader... though not sure if its loading my Angular 1 modules...

Comment: Do you import '@angular/upgrade' in your vendor?

Comment: @HaHoang I did not, but it didn't seem to help when I included it

Comment: You can need to upgrade to 1.5.x in order to perform an upgrade. Also take a look at: https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/issues/288

Comment: I'm at 1.5.8. 

I saw that issue, though I'm not convinced it's the same problem. Thanks for looking into it though @HaHoang!